# Slider going back to its original position (onEditingChanged)

Tags: swiftui, charts, slider, oneditingchanged

I have a slider that controls the day of the year. In the chart the calculations are time consuming, so if you move the slider a lot it can take an age to finish the update, as it's regenerating each intermediary view.

[image]

So, I introduced an onEditingChanged to manage this.

```
HStack {
      Slider(value: $daySlider, in: 0...364, onEditingChanged: { (isBegin) in
          if isBegin {
                sliderUpdate = false  // Begins sliding
          } else {
                sliderUpdate = true   // Finishes sliding
          }
     })
 }
```

There are two related phenomena going on here:

i) When you release the slider it goes back to its original value.

ii) Due to the way I have written the interim code the chart evaporates whilst the slider is being moved, so you just see.

[image]

The code for the chart is, where sliderUpdate is a State variable:

```
 func AnimatedChart()->some View{
        if sliderUpdate == true {
            Chart{
                let filteredArray = solarElevation.filter { $0.day == Int(daySlider) }
                ForEach(filteredArray) {item in
                    LineMark(
                        x: .value("Hour", ((Calendar.current.dateComponents(components, from: item.date).hour!))+1),
                        y: .value("Elevation", item.elevation),
                        series: .value("Hour", "Elevation")
                    )
                    .interpolationMethod(.catmullRom)
                    .lineStyle(StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2))
                    .foregroundStyle(.blue)
                }
                let filteredArrayHour = solarElevation.filter { $0.day == Int(daySlider) && $0.hour == Int(hourSlider) }
                ForEach(filteredArrayHour) {itemRule in

                    RuleMark(x: .value("Hour", itemRule.hour + 1))
                        .foregroundStyle(Color.orange)
                        .lineStyle(StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 1))
                    PointMark(
                        x: .value("Hour", itemRule.hour + 1),
                        y: .value("Elevation", itemRule.elevation)
                    )
                    .foregroundStyle(.orange)
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 300)
            .chartXAxisLabel(position: .bottom, alignment: .center) { Text("Hours") }
           // .chartXScale(domain: 0...24)
            .chartXAxis{
                AxisMarks(values: [0, 6, 12, 18, 24])
            }
            .chartYScale(domain: -90...90)
            .onAppear {
                daySlider = Double(Celestial().calculateDayOfYear(Date()))
                animateGraph()
            }
        }
        else {
        }
    }
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: The problem seems to originate from an .onAppear, which sets the slider to today's date. Without the onEditingChanged it is run only once. With that feature it seems to get called each time the slider is moved.